# How can I disable all contraints in my postgresql?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have a PostgreSQL database with tables that have more than 500 billions rows. I'm trying to delete around 6 millions row but it's takes more than 4 minutes. I need to optimize those delete operation to make an useful system.

I think a good idea could be to disable constraints and triggers and then enable it back, so my questions are:

How can I disable all constraints?
And, is it possible to disable relations between tables?

Right now, I just disable the triggers using this:

```
Alter table "table_name" disable all
```

And enable it back using this:

```
Alter table "table_name" enable all
```

### **Edit**

This is the query result with triggers enabled.

```
  Delete on "ParameterValues"  (cost=0.00..1015910.71 rows=47196359 width=6) (actual time=296995.938..296995.938 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=6000000 read=420811 dirtied=93346 written=51646
  ->  Seq Scan on "ParameterValues"  (cost=0.00..1015910.71 rows=47196359 width=6) (actual time=7977.126..19798.361 rows=6000000 loops=1)
        Filter: ("Id" < 23000000)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 34218414
        Buffers: shared read=420811 dirtied=49228 written=51646
Planning Time: 304.085 ms
Execution Time: 296995.963 ms
```

Disabling all triggers I improve the performance reducing the execution time from 5 minutes to 3 minutes.

```
Alter table "table_name" disable trigger all
```

However, I need to improve more delete operations. Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct statement to disable all triggers on a table is

```
ALTER TABLE atable DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

This will disable all triggers and foreign key constraints defined on the table, since foreign key constraints are implemented by system triggers in PostgreSQL.

It will also disable *deferrable* primary key, unique and exclusion constraints, which are also implemented with triggers. Non-deferrable primary key, unique and exclusion constraints have no associated triggers and are not affected.

You can later re-enable these constraints by enabling the triggers, but there won't be any check for consistency. Because that is dangerous, disabling such triggers requires superuser privileges.

An alternative way to disable trigger-based constraints is to set the [`session_replication_role`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SESSION-REPLICATION-ROLE) parameter to `replica`, which also requires superuser privileges.

The only way to disable check constraints and non-deferrable primary key, unique and exclusion constraints is to drop them and later re-create them. The latter will take some time as it checks the table for consistency, but you may still win out, since it will make data modifications faster.

For reference see the documentation of [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure pl/pgsql solution. you may use an anonymous block like this( or even a function with table name and schema as arguments).

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
l_tab_name    TEXT := 'yourtablename';
l_schema_name TEXT := 'public';
rec record;

BEGIN
for rec IN
(
SELECT rel.relname as table_name ,con.conname as constraint_name
       FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel
                       ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp
                       ON nsp.oid = connamespace
       WHERE nsp.nspname     = l_schema_name
             AND rel.relname = l_tab_name
)
  LOOP

       EXECUTE format ('ALTER TABLE %I 
                        DROP CONSTRAINT %I',rec.table_name,rec.constraint_name );

  END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Comment: I have obtained 0 updated rows. I just took your code and replaced l_tab_name value with the name of my table.

Comment: @Jorge Garcia : That's not how you validate something. First use a test table with various constraints. After, successfully  running this block, describe the table and check if you can see the same constraints